# How to create Oracle database table with so many columns and same column datatype in python

Tags: python, database, oracle

I could not solve this problem for a week. 
I have a python list which containing headers. I would like to use these headers to create a table in Oracle database. The problem is that there are more than 50 headers. Also, there are more than 400 lists that I need to use to create tables. Also, all headers have same column datatype.
     I know how to do this job manually. However, if I do it manually, I am too stupid. So, I am looking for some ways that can do it automatically. I have been searched for one week. But I still could not find a solution. Please help me. Thank youuuuuuuuu.

Comment: Hello & welcome to Stack Overflow Edwin! Please see the **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article before posting next time.
Also consider clicking **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46020976/edit)** on
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I guess after a week you found out at least how to connect to a database from a python program?

Comment: Connection works very good. I used cx_Oracle to connect to Oracle db.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved this question by myself with help of Google. 
I did not use pandas dataframe.to_sql because I got an encoding problem.

**Solution 1:**
dffs0 has a list of column names. I just used a very inefficient way to add CHAR(100) for each column names.

```
col_name1 = [] 
for col_name in dffs0:
    col_name = col_name + " CHAR(100)"
    col_name1.append(col_name)
```

Then,

```
sql='create table test1 %s' % (col_name1)
sql = sql.replace('[','(').replace(']',')').replace("'",'')
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This works for me.

**Solution 2:**
I solved the encoding problem of the dataframe.to_sql. So, I can use this convenient way to import tables to Oracle db. But, the default datatype is clob which is not convenient. So, I used a for loop to change the datatypes of columns.

```
dffs1.to_sql("fs_%s"  %(id), engine, dtype={col_name: NVARCHAR(1000) for col_name in cols},if_exists='replace' )
```

cols has a list of column names. dffs1 is the dataframe be imported into Oracle db.

Both solutions work for me. 
I don't know why people voted down my question. I am a new user of python and oracle db. Before I ask this question here, I have google for more than 10 hours. The solution is simple, but it is not that easy for a new user. And, I don't think the first solution is the most efficient way even though it works. I am still looking for more efficient ways. Also, it seems that some people are not that friendly. Anyway, I have figured it out by myself.